# ASP.NET Core with Entity Framework doesn't read seeded data from SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, ssms

This is code-first, ASP.NET Core 2.1 with EF, SQL Server 2017. Everything appears to work fine - I can read data through the app when it's been inserted from the app itself.

I tried inserting a bulk of data into an existing table from SSMS. I can see all the entries when I `select *` in SSMS, but the entries are not recognized by EF. It's as if the app only recognizes the entries that were inserted from EF.

Comment: Make sure you're no looking at two different databases. Anyway, with this amount of info it's impossible to help you.

Comment: Also make sure your CodeFirst isn't dropping and recreating the table at runtime.